# Can I insert user messages in a package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line, package.json

I have a package.json file which specifies a file to be compiled and placed in the `bin/` directory as such.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel scripts/index.js --out-dir bin",
  "start": "node bin/index.js"
}
```

The user is to run `npm run build` and then `npm run start`. If the user immediately runs `npm run start`, skipping the first step, and thus there's no index.js file to run in `bin/`, I'd like for her to receive a message saying "please run `npm run build` to create the index file in bin." Is there an easy way to do this in the package.json?

Comment: You can concatenate multiple commands with `;` between them, and thus with a little bash-fu verify first if the bin folder exists, but it's not really elegant, and need some effort to be OS-independant. I would just write a notice in the README of your project.

Comment: You could consider utilizing a [post- hook](https://medium.com/yld-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf) in your _package.json_. For instance; if you define a [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) hook in the `scripts` section of your _package.json_, e.g. `"postinstall": "npm run build"`, then the `build` script will be automatically invoked after the user installs your package - therefore ensuring that `index.js` exists in `bin/`.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that in the `bin/index.js` by adding a `try catch` and tell the user what's wrong you can even add a `console.log("message")` to say you should run build first.

Comment: Wouldn't be in the package.json, as asked in the question.

Comment: he have the choice this is what am proposing of course there's other method may be better than mine i am just trying to help thanks @Veve

Comment: "If the user immediately runs npm run start, skipping the first step, and thus there's no index.js file to run in bin/..."